# PhpStorm простановка закрывающей фигурной скобки на новой строке у namespase'ов?

Tags: php, phpstorm, jetbrains

При подключении неймспейсов в секции `use` и использовании "Optimize Imports" если пространства имён были сгруппированы, то закрывающая фигурная скобка ставится на той же строке, что и последнее подключение. Как сделать так, чтобы она ставилась на следующей строке? Как пример:

```
use app\models\{
    User,
    Settings,
    Site
}
```

Сейчас получается так:

```
use app\models\{
    User,
    Settings,
    Site}
```

`Wrapping and Braces` → `Braces Placement` → `Other` → `Next line` не подходит, т.к. это только для кода в классах и функциях

Comment: нафиг оно тебе надо, клацай CTRL+ALT+L (Reformat Code) периодически - это авторасстановка кода (скобки, кавычки, пробелы и тд)

Comment: @Jean-Claude так это не помогает тоже. В методах/функциях да, это всё становится красивым как надо, расставляются скобки где нужно, а вот у неймспейсов нет. В этом-то и проблема